# Comparing two objects always returns false

Tags: java, object, compare, equals

I'm trying to create a simple date class. My professor also wants us to include our own .equals method in the date class which should compare two objects. My problem is my method returns false unless I compare the exact same object, even if their values are the same.

Here is my driver:

```
public class Lab3Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Date theDate = new Date(6, 30, 1995);
     Date anotherDate = new Date(6, 30, 1995);
     System.out.println(theDate.equals(anotherDate));
     System.out.println(theDate);
     System.out.println(anotherDate);
    }
}
```

Here is my date class:

```
public class Date {
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;
    public Date() // default no arg constructor
    {
        this.month = 1; // set to date I completed this class, for fun.
        this.day = 26;
        this.year = 2019;
    }

    public Date(int m, int d, int y) // normal constructor in case you want to initialize variables upon object declaration
    {
        this.month = m;
        this.day = d;
        this.year = y;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month)
    {
        if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) // if else that checks and makes sure months are between 1 and 12
        {
            this.month = month;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid month input. Months are between 1 and 12.");
        }
    }

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day)
    {
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 31) // if else that checks and makes sure days are between 1 and 31
        {
            this.day = day;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid day input. Days are between 1 and 31.");
        }
    }

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) // year can be set to anything, in the case that this program is used for something
    {                             // other than the present day, as in a reference to the past or future
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString() // to string in order to print out the date that is stored
    {
        String theDate = "The date is: " + this.month + "/" + this.day + "/" + this.year;
        return theDate;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object that) // compares two objects and checks for null/type casting
    {
        if (this == that)
            return true;
        else if(that == null || that.getClass()!= this.getClass())
        {
            System.out.println("Null or type casting of argument.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Something with this method is creating a problem I think:

```
 public boolean equals(Object that) // compares two objects and checks for null/type casting
    {
        if (this == that)
            return true;
        else if(that == null || that.getClass()!= this.getClass())
        {
            System.out.println("Null or type casting of argument.");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Think about what cases will allow your method to return True. `==` is only checking if they're literally the same object, not if they have value equality. You'll need to compare all the fields of the class.

Comment: well, where do you *actually* compare the objects? Basically nowhere, your `equals` method is basically `return this == that;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this == that)
```

This line does not compare the objects. This only verifies if your object is in the same memory space, basically asking if it is exactly the same object (pointing to the same place).

If you want to compare two different objects, two different instances like

```
Date theDate = new Date(6, 30, 1995);
Date anotherDate = new Date(6, 30, 1995);
```

then you'll have to add more lines of code that check each value in each variable in each of the objects, or override the ' == ' method to make it compare the values.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, because you wrote

```
else {
   return false;
}
```

So whenever `that` object has a different reference and is from the same class you go in the else statement above which returns false. 
You should implement the code instead of returning false, for example:

```
public boolean equals(Object that) // compares two objects and checks for null/type casting
{
    if (this == that)
        return true;
    else if(that == null || that.getClass()!= this.getClass())
    {
        System.out.println("Null or type casting of argument.");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return this.year == that.getYear() && ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sοme οther things tο nοte:

As Nate has already said, yοu have tο cοmpare the individual fields οf the twο οbjects yοu are cοmparing. Tο dο that, yοu can use `return year == that.getYear() && day == that.getDay() && mοnth == that.getMοnth()`.

But wait! Yοur `equals` methοd takes in an `Object`. Therefοre, we can't use thοse methοds. There are twο ways yοu can fix this.

1. Dο an `instanceοf` check at the beginning οf the methοd, and then cast the parameter tο a `Date` οbject.
2. Restrict the parameter οf yοur methοd tο οnly allοw `Date` οbjects.

Persοnally, I wοuld dο the latter, since an errοr will pοp up at cοmpile time if yοu used a nοn-`Date` οbject. Hοwever, if yοu did a type check in methοd and thrοw an exceptiοn if the type check failed, yοu may never nοtice an errοr if yοu prοvided an argument that is nοt a `Date` οbject until the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to make sure that if you override the **equals** method you should also override the **hashCode** method.

For your reference, please read the section
https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts#hashcode

I have completed both the overridden methods for you.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (this == that)
            return true;
        
        if(!(that instanceof Date))
            return false;
        
        if(that == null || that.getClass()!= this.getClass())
            return false;
        
        Date anotherDate = (Date) that;
        if(this.month == anotherDate.month
                && this.day == anotherDate.day
                && this.year == anotherDate.year)
            return true;
        
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (month ^ (month >>> 16));
        result = prime * result + (int) (day ^ (day >>> 16));
        result = prime * result + (int) (year ^ (year >>> 16));
        
        return result;
    }
```